# layoutIfNeeded function behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, layout

I am using a lot of gradient drawing using this function:

```
func drawGradient(colors: [CGColor], locations:  [NSNumber]) {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame.size = self.frame.size
    gradientLayer.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0.0,y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.colors = colors
    gradientLayer.locations = locations
    print(self.frame.size)
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

The problem is that if I don't call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` in `viewDidLoad()` of `UIViewController` my gradient doesn't cover whole screen on iPhone X+. But if I call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` it makes my app crash on iOS 9.x and act weird on iPhone 5/5s. I really do not know any workaround and need help to understand how it all works.

Comment: When you call `drawGradient`, you must be sure that view has correct frame.

Comment: yes I get that, but I need to call this inside cell's setup etc, I have to force my view to layout, but it makes my app crash on iOS 9.x

Comment: Where are you calling `drawGradient`?

Comment: currently in `viewDidLoad` and in cell's setup (`cellForRowAt`)

Comment: Move the call in `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  You need to wait until Auto Layout has sized the frame.

Comment: Be careful though because `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called more than once, so make sure you only call `drawGradient` once.  You can add a property to your `viewController` called `var appliedGradient = false` and then check it before applying the gradient and flip it to `true`.

Comment: yeah that've worked but what to do with those from `UITableViewCells` and `UICollectionViewCells`

Comment: Are you using custom cells?  Do you subclass `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell`?  If so, override `layoutSubviews` and call `drawGradient` after `super.layoutSubviews()`.  Again, make sure you only call it once.

Comment: if you add this like answer - I will confirm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `drawGradient` in `viewDidLoad`.  That is too early.  You need to wait until *Auto Layout* has sized the frame.
Move the call in `viewDidLoad` to an override of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  Be careful though because `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called more than once, so make sure you only call `drawGradient` once. You can add a property to your viewController called `var appliedGradient = false` and then check it before applying the gradient and flip it to `true`.

For your custom subclasses of `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell`, override `layoutSubviews` and call `drawGradient` after `super.layoutSubviews()`. Again, make sure you only call it once.

---

**Note:**  If your `frame` could resize (due to rotation of the phone) or differing cell sizes, you should keep track of the previous gradient layer and replace it with a new one in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` for your viewController and in `layoutSubviews` for your cells.

Here I've modified your `drawGradient` to make a global function called `applyGradient` that adds a gradient to a view.  It replaces a previous gradient layer if there was one:

```
func applyGradient(colors: [CGColor], locations: [NSNumber], to view: UIView, replacing prior: CALayer?) -> CALayer {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame.size = view.frame.size
    gradientLayer.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0.0,y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.colors = colors
    gradientLayer.locations = locations
    print(view.frame.size)
    if let prior = prior {
        view.layer.replaceSublayer(prior, with: gradientLayer)
    } else {
        view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
    return gradientLayer
}
```

And it is used like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // property to keep track of the gradient layer
    var gradient: CALayer?

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        gradient = applyGradient(colors: [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor],
            locations: [0.0, 1.0], to: self.view, replacing: gradient)
    }
}
```